# Invoke destructor manually and reuse memory

Tags: c++, destructor, explicit-destructor-call

While I understand that this is probably not the best of ideas, I ask hypothetically:

> Is it legal to (i.e. defined behavior) to invoke an object's
>   destructor manually, and then reuse the memory for another object?

Definitions:

```
class A {
  int a, b, c;
  A() {}
  ~A() {}
}

A createObject() {
  A object;
  return object;
}
```

Code:

```
A* object = new A();
// Use object...
object->~A();
*object = createObject();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a destructor explicitly is a legal thing to do - in fact, that's what you do when you use *placement `new`*. Initializing an object "in place", when the memory is already allocated, is also a legal thing do do, but you should do it differently: rather than using the assignment operator, you could use this syntax:

```
object = new (object) A(); // Placement syntax
```

The way you did it (with an assignment operator) is incorrect, because you are calling a function (i.e. the assignment operator) on an object the destructor of which has completed.

Comment: Initializing an object "in place", when the memory is already allocated, is also a legal thing do do, provided the memory allocated for the old object is enough to fit the new object. For some allocators, I think some care ought to be taken if the objects' sizes are different (the allocator might want to free less memory than it allocated)...

Comment: @Massa If the object is managing memory internally, this may not work. For example, consider an object that has a pointer to a C string, which it deletes in the destructor. By the rule of three, the object will also have to delete or otherwise manage that same pointer in the assignment operator. However, the pointer will become invalid after the call of destructor, which may cause undefined behavior in the assignment operator.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my answer: I was just qualifying your phrase <<Initializing an object "in place", when the memory is already allocated, is also a legal thing do do>>... It may not be legal, if, for instance, the new object is larger than the old or if they have different allocators or if they have different sizes and the allocator take the size of the object in consideration when deallocating.

Comment: @Massa - in the original question, though, if you use an explicit destructor call and placement new to put in a different type than the original object you've got undefined behavior; the compiler will call the destructor of the original type when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: will `delete` do that? because in the original question, the destructor is only called on `delete`, it's a pointer!

Answer (score 6):

You can't call the assignment operator on a destroyed object like you are doing.   At least not generally, though it might work with some types.  What you can do is this though:

```
A* object = new A();
object->~A();
// Placement new.
// Constructs a new object in the memory pointed to by object pointer.
// Doesn't allocate memory.
new (object) A(createObject());
```

You can even use placement new to construct objects of a different type in that memory, as long as they fit.  Just be sure of two things:

1. Don't ever construct an object on top of an already existing object that has not been destructed.
2. Don't ever call `delete` on a pointer after you've called the destructor on the object it points to until you've re-construced an object (of the same type) in its place.